# Why can't に対して be used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions, set-phrases

I'm currently using the 新完全マスター N2 Grammar book. One of the questions required completing the following sentence:

> 今回の選挙では、環境税 () 候補者たちの意見が対立している。

Two of the options were に対して and をめぐって, and をめぐって was marked as the right answer. I understand why をめぐって works here, but in the textbook, one of the usages of に対して was described as "X についてある感情を持つ". For me, it felt appropriate for this sentence (as the candidates have different opinions/feelings on the environmental taxes).
I would be glad to know if using に対して in this sentence would be an outright mistake, and if so - why?

Answer (score 1):

Since they are in te-form, they should connect with 対立している. Using に対して here may be not entirely impossible here, but Xをめぐって対立している=(*opinions are*) *opposing each other **around** X* is much better in collocation. (Probably *opposing each other/varying towards X* is just as odd in English.)

---

If 環境税（） connects with 意見, then （）must be in attributive form (連体形).

- 環境税に対する候補者たちの意見が対立している Opinions of candidates towards 環境税 ...

Xに対す**る**意見 is fairly normal.

Comment: Thank you!
Do you think that に対する fits the meaning of the sentence, or is をめぐって still a better choice?

Comment: @בנימיןליפשיץ に対する is ok, but をめぐって is more idiomatic.